# TSQL same SELECT with variable WHERE condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I need to run the following simple query from SQL SERVER Management Studio

```
SELECT a FROM myTable WHERE b = 'X';
```

The value of X corresponds to a text file as

```
x1
x2
x3
...
x40000
```

In ither words, I need to loop through the values in the text file.

This must be simple but I cannot really find a way to do it other than the naive case of running the query 40000 times.

EDIT:  I was already told off in the comments that I should simply import the values into a temporary table and then JOIN as required.  That is fair. Appreciate the comment.

Any idea will be welcome!

Thanks

Comment: Run from where? There's insufficient information here.

Comment: Hi @KenWhite, from SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Import the text file into a temp table, and then work with that temp table to do whatever you need using a JOIN

Comment: Is this to be "one query selecting ~40000 rows" or "~40000 queries selecting 0-1 rows each"?  Also, if you are doing this from SMSS then can you open the file and just wrap a prefix and a suffix on each line to make the each line the query you require?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I well understood the case: you have two data sources, the first is a **SQL Table** and the Other is a **Text file** and you make a **Loop** generate the result.

In this case, I would suggest you import the data of txt into a **table** at once,
Then you make **join** between the **two tables** so that can be done in one query execution.